# Django view return vs yield?

Tags: python, django

That might be quite strange or stupid question, but why can't I use `yield` instead of `return` in Django views?
Lets say I have simple view:

```
def return_index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Why next view does not work in Django:

```
def yield_index(request):
    list_of_templates = ['index.html', 'foo.html', 'bar.html']
    for i in range(len(list_of_templates)):
        time.sleep(5)
        yield render(request, list_of_templates[i])
```

Assuming that `yield_index` view will return different views every 5 seconds.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Once you've returned a complete response (which render is doing here) - the browser has its page and that's it - you've responded to *the* request it made - HTTP works on a single request/single response (sure you could stream a response but that's completely different) - it doesn't make sense to make a request (even if it was possible) to then get - oh okay, here's 3 different pages for it...

Comment: @Jon Clements♦  ok, that might be the same page, but with different contexts - some kind of "async" response.

Comment: In which case you have one response of the "master" page, but within that ajax requests or whatever to then make requests providing the other parts with their context... So your view would return the index.html by default, in that it contains requests (possibly something like index.html?section=foo) and then your view function (if you wanted to keep it all in one) would then return the rendering of that template etc...

Comment: Although you'd probably want to restructure it depending if they're re-used etc... a basic example without error checking would be: `template = request.GET.get('section', 'index'); return render(request, f'{template}.html')`

Comment: @Jon Clements♦ yes, I know about ajax, but just wanted to know if there is a possibility to access similar functionlaity on pure Django

Comment: As mentioned above - no there isn't. That's just not how HTTP works - Django or no Django.

Comment: @Jon Clements♦ if you read a second answer - looks like it is possible using `StreamingHttpResponse`

Comment: Yup... but still only making a single response... and there's no guarantee the browser will render the content until it's received all/most of it anyway depending on what you're sending it and they're not always that robust. All that's happening in that case is it's a convoluted way of just having `index.html` be `{% include 'foo.html' %}{% include 'bar.html' %}` and then rendering that...

Answer (score 2):

use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse)

for example in `view.py`:

```
import time
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def yield_index(t):
    list_of_templates = ['index.html', 'foo.html']
    for i in range(len(list_of_templates)):
        time.sleep(t)
        yield list_of_templates[i] #render(request, list_of_templates[i])

def home(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(yield_index(5))
```

Comment: Wow did not know about that option :)